# Time based cache for single element

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The container should be thread safe and provide lazy load of data, and cache the data for set period of time.

```
public class TimeBasedExpirationCache<T> {
    private static class CacheElement<T> {
        private final Future<T> data;
        private final Instant created;

        private CacheElement(Future<T> data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.created = Instant.now();
        }

        public T get() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            return data.get();
        }

        public Future<T> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public Instant getCreated() {
            return created;
        }
    }

    private final Supplier<T> computable;
    private final long validTime;
    private AtomicReference<CacheElement<T>> data = new AtomicReference<>();

    public TimeBasedExpirationCache(Supplier<T> computable, long validTime) {
        this.computable = computable;
        this.validTime = validTime;
    }

    public T getData() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            CacheElement<T> oldValue = data.get();
            if (oldValue == null || hasExpired(oldValue)) {
                FutureTask<T> ft = new FutureTask<>(computable::get);
                CacheElement<T> newElement = new CacheElement<>(ft);
                boolean swapped = data.compareAndSet(oldValue, newElement);
                if (swapped) {
                    if (oldValue != null) oldValue.getData().cancel(true);
                    oldValue = newElement;
                    ft.run();
                }else{
                    oldValue = data.get();
                }
            }
            try {
                return oldValue.get();
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                data.set(null);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean hasExpired(CacheElement<T> element) {
        return element.getCreated().plusMillis(validTime).isBefore(Instant.now());
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. the `FutureTask` is not executed in threadpool since the thread that creates future will serve as thread that loads the data.
2. `CacheElement` is created to have immutable data, thus there is no need for further synchronization from the the code, and we can delegate all sync. mechanism to underlying java classes - in this case `AtomicReference`.

Is there something to improve? Some standard way of annotating of classes indicating thread safety, better more correct exception handling, anything.

Comment: You absolutely need to document the working principle in the JavaDocs. The getData method is way too complex to be "self-documenting" so it needs documentation too. I haven't had enough coffee this morning so I won't even bother to try to figure out what your code does to give a proper review.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I have had a few cups of coffee now. :)

For documenting tread safety, the following is quite common:

```
/**
 * This class is thread safe.
 */
```

In addition to that, if you are trying to be thread safe, you need to document in the code the principle that you think ensures the thread safety. In your case, the fact that you construct a `CacheElement` that is thrown away in case there is a race condition on updating the `AtomicReference`.

You need to spend more time thinking about naming. The names of the variables need to describe the purpose *why* the variable exists, not just what they are. You're throwing in the word `data` everywhere. Sometimes "data" represents a future task that calls the suplier that provides the cached value, sometimes "data" represents a reference to a container containing the future task that calls the suplier that provides the cached value. Plain "data" is almost always a bad name.

Renaming `CacheElement` to `CachedValueContainer` would higfhlight that it is not actually the value that is cached, just a container for it. Element and value can be somewhat synonymous.

Some suggestions for better names:

```
private AtomicReference<CacheElement<T>> cacheContainerReference =
    new AtomicReference<>();

CachedValueContainer<T> oldContainer = cacheContainerReference.get();

public TimeBasedExpirationCache(
        final Supplier<T> cachedValueSupplier,
        final long validTimeMillis) {
```

The catch block for the `CancellationException` should explain when the exception occurs and why it is ignored (the possibility that a thread is waiting in FutureTask.get() while another thread swaps the element to a new one and cancels the old one). Mentioning that this is also the reason for the "non-infinite infinite loop" would be good too.

There should be a way to put hard limit on the infinite loop. Just to make sure you don't end up bitten by some weird corner case.

Never throw pure `RuntimeException`. Define your own exception class that extends RuntimeException and throw that. You probably can use the same exception when handling the infinite loop hard limit. Runtime exceptions must always be documented in JavaDoc since the compiler will not warn about them.

Answer (score 2):

I see no major issues here. It's fine code.

I do notice that, since the expiration time counts from when the task *begins*, and since there is no check for time taken between waiting for the value and returning it (as both happen in the same `return oldValue.get()` statement), it seems to be possible to return a value after the time it (arguably) should have expired. When the time it takes to produce a value is consistently shorter than the time a value should be valid for this is a non-issue, but it may be worth considering what should happen if that isn't always be the case - I'm not saying the behaviour needs to change, but it should probably be documented.

Aside from that, I only have a couple nitpicks about style:

- Besides noticing the use of `plusMillis` in the source of `hasExpired`, there seems to be nothing to indicate that the duration is specified in milliseconds - might having the constructor take a `TemporalAmount` instead of a `long` make things clearer? Or, if taking the duration as a `long` is desirable, perhaps the parameter could be renamed to specify the unit, maybe to something like `validDurationMillis`?
- I'm not sold on the naming of `get` and `getData` in `CacheElement`, it feels a bit muddled conceptually - surely the cached data is the return value of `get`? And the `Future` returned by `getData` is only ever used to cancel the task at hand, in which case the value returned by `getData` *probably contains no data*. Perhaps `get` could be called `getData` and `getData` could be called `getTask`?
- Also, javadoc is nice to have, and this code seems to lack it entirely. Now, much of the interface here is fairly self-explanatory (which is good!), but there should probably be a way to find out stuff like which thread is responsible for producing a value (or, as mentioned earlier, which unit to use when specifying a cache's expiration time) apart from reading the source code.

Answer (score 2):

### `Duration`

One small issue… You pass around your time to expire as a a mere `long` for a count of milliseconds. But we have a class for that: [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

A `Duration` object is more convenient:

- The programmer need not be reminding themselves in this is a count of seconds, or of milliseconds, or of microseconds, or of nanoseconds, etc.
- Using a `Duration` relieves the calling programmer of the bother of converting their desired amount of time into a count of milliseconds. Besides which that calculation is trivially easy to get wrong without noticing.

A `Duration` represents an amount of time unattached to the timeline, on the scale of “days“ (as 24-hour chunks of time, unrelated to the calendar), hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional second in nanoseconds.

The following two lines are equivalent; the calling programmer can use whichever they want.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ) ;
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis( 5_000 ) ;
```

Replace your `long validTime` with a `Duration` object.

And as [TorbenPutkonen mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/291119/42274), think about naming more carefully. Give the most specific meaningful name you can devise.

And, I like to use `final` on constructor parameters, to ensure they are not inadvertently re-assigned.

So this:

```
public TimeBasedExpirationCache( Supplier<T> computable, long validTime)     
{
    this.computable = computable;
    this.validTime = validTime;
}
```

… becomes this:

```
public TimeBasedExpirationCache( final Supplier<T> computable, final Duration untilExpiration )     
{
    this.computable = computable;
    this.untilExpiration = untilExpiration ;
}
```

For math, pass your `Duration` object to [`Instant#plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#plus(java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount)). So this:

```
return element.getCreated().plusMillis(validTime).isBefore(Instant.now());
```

… becomes:

```
return element.getCreated().plus( this.untilExpiration ).isBefore( Instant.now() );
```

---

Your Question happens to touch the [two toughest problems](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) in programming: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.